# Having trouble pushing 6.6L bar into pin connectors

Tags: technic

I have a dilemma where I am trying to push a 6.6L bar(4095)through 3 stacked pin connectors(62462) that have 1 long pin(6558) and 2 pins (4459) inserted. The bar only goes in a little bit and then it won't budge. I have a picture of it, if that would be helpful.

Comment: I second the motion for the picture idea.

Answer (score 1):

The 2L pin normally fits a bar easily. But, there are older versions that have thicker sides (you can tell by the lip on the ends); you might check to see that yours are all the newer kind.

3L friction pins are all thicker, and do not allow a bar to pass through.